# ThreadPoolExecutor: pool control state CTL

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to understand internals of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and looking at its source code.

To being with, I saw this section:

```
    private final AtomicInteger ctl = new AtomicInteger(ctlOf(RUNNING, 0));
    private static final int COUNT_BITS = Integer.SIZE - 3;
    private static final int CAPACITY   = (1 << COUNT_BITS) - 1;

    // runState is stored in the high-order bits
    private static final int RUNNING    = -1 << COUNT_BITS;
    private static final int SHUTDOWN   =  0 << COUNT_BITS;
    private static final int STOP       =  1 << COUNT_BITS;
    private static final int TIDYING    =  2 << COUNT_BITS;
    private static final int TERMINATED =  3 << COUNT_BITS;

    // Packing and unpacking ctl
    private static int runStateOf(int c)     { return c & ~CAPACITY; }
    private static int workerCountOf(int c)  { return c & CAPACITY; }
    private static int ctlOf(int rs, int wc) { return rs | wc; }
```

This seems daunting, I couldn't understand the usage of these final variables e.g. `RUNNING`, `SHUTDOWN`, `// Packing and unpacking ctl`. What is `ctl` (represented by `AtomicInteger`)?

I want to understand how it works internally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [about ThreadPoolExecutor member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995704/about-threadpoolexecutor-member-variable)

Comment: This one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309451/workercountof-method-in-threadpoolexecutor-java

Comment: @Savior: Thanks for the link, however my question is about other aspects also, for example: `runStateOf(int c)` , `workerCountOf(int c)` etc. The SO question which you provide is ok, but very succinct.